# Python, Selenium. Как парсить таблицу?

Tags: python, selenium

Сайт e-library, дохожу до получения таблицы на сайте, но проблема, не могу её спарсить, не могу найти хорошую документацию по selenium'у. К тому же, таблица может меняться в зависимости от указанных фильтров. Моя цель: чтобы селениум парсил любую таблицу, которую даст сайт, либо выдавал сообщение *данных нету, но на процессе парсинга застрял(
p.s.Делал по чужому примеру

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
    import time
    
    url = 'https://elibrary.ru/'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    binary_yandex_driver_file = 'yandexdriver.exe' # path to YandexDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(binary_yandex_driver_file, options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    original_window = driver.current_window_handle
    assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1
    
    try:
        xpath = '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a'
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        elem.click()
    
        xpath2 = '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[6]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a'
        elem2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath2)))
        elem2.click()
    
        wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
    
        for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
            if window_handle != original_window:
                driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
                break
    
        form_xpath = '/html/body/center/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/input'
        elem3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, form_xpath)))
        print(elem3)
        elem3.send_keys('Кромина Л А')
        
        xpath4 = '/html/body/center/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a'
        elem4 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath4)))
        elem4.click()
        time.sleep(4)
        
        driver.switch_to.window(original_window)
        time.sleep(4)
    
        select_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'begin_year')
        select = Select(select_element)
        option_list = select.options
        select.select_by_value('2021')
        
        select_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'end_year')
        select = Select(select_element)
        option_list = select.options
        select.select_by_value('2024')
        time.sleep(4)
        
        
        xpath5 = '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[11]/tbody/tr/td[6]/a' #поиск
        elem5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath5)))
        elem5.click()
        
     #ПЫТАЮСЬ ПАРСИТЬ (ДАЛЕЕ ВНИЗ)
        rows = 1+len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
        "/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]"))
     
    # Obtain the number of columns in table
        cols = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
        "/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"))
     
    # Print rows and columns
        print(rows)
        print(cols)
     
    # Printing the table headers
        print("Locators           "+"             Description")
        for r in range(2, rows+1):
            for p in range(1, cols+1):
           
            # obtaining the text from each column of the table
                value = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                    "/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]["+str(r)+"]/td[2]["+str(p)+"]").text
                print(value, end='       ')
            print()
     
    # Printing the data of the table
    
    
    
        
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос хороший, но оформлен конечно неправильно (указывайте пожалуйста к комментариях какие элементы вы затрагиваете при работе).
Давайте разбираться.

Я буду работать с chromedriver для примера.

Начнем.

1. Изначально нам нужна страница поиска, значит проще сразу перейти к
   ней, а не искать её в коде сайта. Заменяем.

   Ваш вариант:

   ```python
   xpath = '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a'
   elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
   elem.click()
   ```

   Мой вариант:

   ```python
   url = 'https://elibrary.ru/querybox.asp?scope=newquery'
   ```
2. Далее проходимся по всем нужным нам элементам, здесь все идет верно,
   до одного момента, а именно, вы зачем-то находите нужного вам
   `Автора`, но не выбираете его, а просто идёте дальше.

   Добавляем:

   ```python
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/center/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a").click() #
   ```

   Выбираем автора
3. Теперь остался только парсинг. Ничего сложного пишем конструкцию,
   которая будет определять количество статей и выводить их заголовки.

   Вот примерный код:

   ```python
   i = 1+len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr"))

   for item in range(2, i): # Считаем со второго, т.к. первый tr - элемент сайта
       get_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[{item}]/td[2]/a/b/span").text
       print(get_text)

   sleep(4)
   ```

Итого получается что-то вроде:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from time import sleep

url = 'https://elibrary.ru/querybox.asp?scope=newquery'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/alexp/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
original_window = driver.current_window_handle
assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1

try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[6]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a").click() # Нажимаем добавить автора
    sleep(2)

    wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

    for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
        if window_handle != original_window:
            driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            break

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/center/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/input").send_keys('Кромина Л А') # Вводим нужные данные
    sleep(2)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/center/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a").click() # Нажимаем поиск
    sleep(2)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/center/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a").click() # Выбираем автора
    sleep(2)
    
    driver.switch_to.window(original_window) # Переключаемся между окнами
    sleep(2)

    select_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'begin_year')
    select = Select(select_element)
    option_list = select.options
    select.select_by_value('2021')
    sleep(2)
    
    select_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'end_year')
    select = Select(select_element)
    option_list = select.options
    select.select_by_value('2024')
    sleep(2)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[11]/tbody/tr/td[6]/a").click() # Нажимаем поиск
    
    i = 1+len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr")) # Считаем кол-во записей
    
    for item in range(2, i): # Считаем со второго, т.к. первый tr - элемент сайта
        get_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[{item}]/td[2]/a/b/span").text # Забираем заголовоки
        print(get_text)
    
    sleep(4)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Читайте документацию, поправляйте примеры под себя, удачи!